# HTML Animation on downloaded Template

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I am relatively new to html programming. Me and my friends want to have a wep page, this is why i downloaded a free template.

In this template there is the "team" section. Because of the fact, that not everything fits on the first page and we do not want to have the buttons to click on, we want it to be animated (It should scroll horizontal to show all team members and should not stop)

Do you have any code, tipps, keywords etc. that can help me to do it?

Screen:

[How it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpF9y.jpg)

Code

```css
/* Team Section */
#tf-team{
 background: url(../img/03.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 color: #ffffff;
}
#tf-team .overlay{
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%, rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8)), color-stop(17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73)), color-stop(35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66)), color-stop(62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cc000000', endColorstr='#66000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
 height: auto;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 padding: 80px 0;
}
.section-title.center{
 padding: 30px 0;
}
.section-title h2,
.section-title.center h2{
 font-weight: 300;
}
.section-title.center .line{
 border-top: 4px solid #fcac45;
 height: 10px;
 width: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.section-title.center hr {
 border-top: 4px solid rgba(252, 172, 69, 0.34);
 width: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 10px;
 position: relative;
 left: 17%;
}
#team{ margin: 0 auto}
#team .item{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 15px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
}

img.img-circle.team-img {
 width: 120px;
 height: 120px;
 border: 4px solid transparent;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}
#tf-team .item .thumbnail:hover>img.img-circle.team-img{
 border: 4px solid #FCAC45;
}
#tf-team .thumbnail {
 background: transparent;
 border: 0;
}

#tf-team .thumbnail .caption {
 padding: 9px;
 color: #F2F2F2;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page span {
 display: block;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 margin: 5px 7px;
 filter: Alpha(Opacity=1);
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 border-radius: 0;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page.active span, 
.owl-theme .owl-controls.clickable .owl-page:hover span {
 filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);
 opacity: 1;
 background: #FFFFFF;
}
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page.active span{
 background: #FCAC45;
}
```

```html
 <!-- Team Page
    ==========================================-->
 <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 <!-- Indicators --> <!-- Your Code -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
     <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
     <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
     
      </ol> <!-- Your Code Indicators Stop -->
    <div id="tf-team" class="text-center">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="section-title center">
                    <h2><strong><span class="color">Unser Team</span></strong></h2>
                    <div class="line">
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"> <!-- Your Code - Begining -->
                <div id="team" class="owl-carousel owl-theme row">
                    <div class="item" alt="Slide 0">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/team/imgtobias.jpg" alt="..." class="img-circle team-img">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Tobias Weninger</h3>
                                <p>Komitee / Öffentlichkeitsarbeit</p>
                                <p>Arschloch... bestes Loch.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" alt="Slide 0">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/team/imglaurenz.jpg" alt="..." class="img-circle team-img">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Laurenz Spatt</h3>
                                <p>Komitee / Projektmanagement</p>
                                <p>Random Zitat.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" alt="Slide 0">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/team/imgherwig.jpg" alt="..." class="img-circle team-img">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Herwig Heiger</h3>
                                <p>Komitee / Whatever</p>
                                <p>....</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" alt="Slide 0">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/team/imgdanial.jpg" alt="..." class="img-circle team-img">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Danial Mohammadi</h3>
                                <p>Komitee / .. </p>
                                <p>..</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" alt="Slide 1">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/team/imgmatthias.jpg" alt="..." class="img-circle team-img">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Matthias Tieber</h3>
                                <p>Komitee / .. </p>
                                <p>....</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item" alt="Slide 1">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/team/imgsimon.jpg" alt="..." class="img-circle team-img">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Simon Federmann</h3>
                                <p>Vorstand / </p>
                                <p>...</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div> <!-- Code Ending -->
               </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap carousel to animate it.
Like in this example :
Four images side by side in each page, the page changes automatically.

```
.item img {width: 25%; height: auto; float:left;}

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 1">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 1">

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 2">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 2">

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 3">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 3">

    </div>        
  </div>

</div>
```

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/ndhthqy8/)

Or you can animate it with owl:

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    items:4,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:1000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true
});

owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay',[1000])
```

[link](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html)

Comment: I added new code to my original question, i know there will be a lot of problems with it. I now got it so that i see two dots underneath the pictures like a menü, but it isn´t moving.

Comment: Wrap your items with <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"> and test if works please

Comment: I wrapped my whole items (i have 5 items) with the <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"> and ended it with </div> underneath all items

Comment: ok have you tried this: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html

Comment: instead of buttons you can call owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay',[1000])  after the function owl.owlCarousel and it will be animated